# How can I create a update trigger for this situation

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

Suppose I have a table ABC and table XYZ.

```
Columns of ABC-->col1 col2 col3 col4 ......coln
Columns of XYZ-->colname oldvalue newvalue modifieddate
```

So when a column ,lets say col1 is updated in ABC , I want that my XYZ should be able to insert a record which has the name of the column being modified , the old value of that column,the new value of the column and the date of modification.
So for every column that is modified in ABC I should get a record in XYZ , Can anyone help me start with this , is it possible firstly,
Any suggestions are welcome,thanks

Comment: if i write update ABC set col1 = 'x', col2 = col2, col2 should be considered as updated?

Comment: @Jānis sorry couldnot get you properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have just asked a question about triggers.

You cant expect us to build all the code for you.

I'll do exactly what I did on your last question and point you to the right direction.

To know if a column was updated you can use the UPDATE(column) keyword

```
create trigger logUpdate
on ABC
After update
as
begin
  if (update(col1)) begin
    --will only get in here if the col1 was referenced on the update statment
     insert into XYZ based ont INSERTED and DELETED tables
  end
end
```

EDIT:
alternative: [CDC](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-%28cdc%29-in-sql-server-2008/)

Comment: And Update(col1) will be considered "true" even if there will be no actual data changes.

Comment: @Diego ya I am not expecting all the code , but can you give me some links to articles where I can try and build my requirement ,I have no prior experience with triggers.Thanks

Comment: hi janis. look at my comment in the code: "--will only get in here if the col1 was referenced on the update statment"

Comment: hi freebird. Thats fine. The code I posted should help you. just give it a try

Comment: @Diego Sorry for silly questions hope you will help me , I have a col1 in ABC , so if it is updated , I want that a new record should be added in XYZ , so if col2,col3 are also updated , that means there must be two new records in XYZ ,is it possible.Thanks for your help.

Comment: of course, in the trigger you can do if (update(col1)) begin .. end and right after if (update(col2)) begin...end and so on

Comment: @Diego , got it that means if my table has 50 columns , I need to write it 50 times , is it

Comment: well, it will depend on how you do your logic. you can always do if (update(col1) or update(col1) ) begin.... or you can check if values on INSERTED and DELETED are different (because if they are the same they have not been updated...

Comment: @Diego , ya the logic has to be formulated , but my question was for every column that is modified , I need to check it by using update(col1),update(col2)..... and so on , no way for looping , I will have to check for every column right ??

Comment: @Diego thanks a lot , last doubt ,if I were to keep track of all data modified in every table , then will I need to create a trigger per table , any alternatives.

Comment: yes you would have to, bu see my edit, I posted a link with a tutorial to CDC. EXTREMELY good SQL Server 2008 functionality that does exactly what you need to do

Answer (score 1):

In trigger I would write something like this for EACH column:

```
Select 'Col1' ColumnName, i.Col1 NewValue, d.Col1 OldValue
From Inserted i 
    Inner Join Deleted d On i.IDCol = d.IDCol
Where 
    (i.Col1 Is Null and Not d.Col1 is Null)
    OR (Not i.Col1 Is Null and d.Col1 is Null)
    OR (Not i.Col1 is Null And Not d.Col1 Is Null AND i.Col1 != d.Col1)
```

In this case- it will take in account if lots of rows are updated in one statement and will log changes only if data has changed.

Its easier if there is NOT NULL columns. And also should consider data types..